# Different ways of overloading functions?

Tags: c++

Could someone confirm whether my understanding of what we can overload on is correct?

- const/non-const
- mutable/non-mutable
- parameter types (obviously)
- number of parameters (obviously)
- NOT return type
- EDIT: Whether the function (not parameter types) is volatile/non-volatile

I am also a little confused whether int, int*, & int and && int can be used to overload a function with the same name? **Would**

```
void X(int);
void X(int*);
void X(int&);
void X(int&&);
```

**be four different overloaded versions of the same function?**

Comment: Int and int* would be different functions, I'd wager int& isn't (since there's no way to distinguish). inline won't either, again, since there's no way to distinguish.

Comment: `inline` is only a hint to the compiler and is completely orthogonal to method resolution and overloading.

Comment: @slugonamission, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e42b016c8b0bf3d617ebcd8ed5bc6173-e434afe6909ff0e74aaeafde0a4175f3

Comment: @slugonamission A reference-type is clearly distinguishable from a  non-reference type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameter types and number of parameters - these are the only ways to distinguish overloaded functions. That covers everything related to parameters, including `int/int &/int &&` distinction, since these are formally different parameter types.

Your `const/non-const` distinction (and don't forget about `volatile`) can be considered as part of parameter type even when it is applied to class method, since in that case it really qualifies the implicit `this` parameter. It is up to you, whether you want to consider this as a parameter-based overloading or as a separate kind of overloading.

I'm not sure what you mean by mutable/non-mutable.

It also has to be said that the language specification has a set of rules that define the concept of *equivalent parameter declarations*, which implies that different (by type) parameter declarations might still be considered equivalent for the purposes of overloading.

Comment: Are you sure about `int/int &`? Even though they may be different types, it seems that they would lead to an ambiguous overload.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I could have sworn there was a way to choose one, but I could be thinking of something else.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: They might by ambiguous in some calls, but still it is not illegal to declare overloaded functions with such parameters. They can be unambiguously resolved when 1) an lvalue is passed as an argument (`int&` is not eligible), 2) explicit cast is used to select one function out of many.

Comment: @AndreyT, That's what I was thinking of! It was casting the function, not the argument!

Comment: I think it was "volatile", not "mutable" you can overload on? EDIT: It seems like you can overload the functions on "volatile" but not the parameter types being volatile?

Comment: @user997112, Top level cv gets discarded.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Are you referring to some new features of `using` specific to C++11? Because in C++03 `using` always exposed *all* inherited overloaded declarations with the given name.

Comment: @chris I don't understand your "cv" message?

Comment: @AndreyT, Good point, they still both have the same name. Of course you could hide them.

Comment: @user997112, cv means const-volatile. When a function parameter has one of those on the "outermost" type, it is discarded.

Comment: No sorry it was just my mis-remembering the feature. I take it back and I'll delete the comment. @chris too.

Comment: @chris if by "outermost" you mean the right-most (or left-most?) why is this the case? Why would the positioning of the function parameter determine whether its ignored or not?

Comment: @user997112, It's making a copy. How can it. If you have `void foo(const int);`, why would it possibly differentiate between passing `5` or a variable declared as `const int`? It's copied anyway. Note that it's still `const` in the function, just not for overload resolution.